# Estrutura de url para post personalizado com tags e listagem de tags

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-types

Olá estou tentando alcançar a seguinte estrutura de url para o `post personalizado` `portifolio`:

- website.com/portifolio - Exibe todos os posts - OK
- website.com/portifolio/slug - Exibe o item do portifolio com o slug `slug` - OK
- **website.com/portifolio/tags - Lista todas as tags relacionadas com o post type - não funciona**
- website.com/portifolio/tags/slug - Exibe todos os posts com a tag de slug `slug` - OK

A tag aqui é uma `custom taxonomy`, taxonomia personalizada criada para o `portifolio`

Alguem já realizou isso com sucesso e pode me dar algum exemplo?

Meu código está assim:

```
register_taxonomy(
    'portfolio_tags',  
    'portfolio',       //post type name
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Tags'
        ),
        'hierarchical'    => false,
        'rewrite'           => array( 
            'slug' => 'portfolio/tags'
         ),
    )
);
register_post_type( 'portfolio',
    array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-portfolio',
      'menu_position' => 5,
      'rewrite'     => array(
          'slug'      => 'portfolio', 
          'with_front'  => false
      )
    )
);
```

Comment: Você criou um template pra essa sua `custom taxonomy` ?

Comment: sim, para exibir o chamado `arquivo` da taxonomia esta ok, eu só queria uma página que fosse o index, onde lista todas as categorias.

Answer (score 1):

Alan, vou tentar entender o que você precisa.
Vc tem o post type portfolios, e a taxonomia criada por você chamada "tags" ?
Vc quer exibir os termos criados nessa sua taxonomia?
Por exemplo, vamos dizer que sua taxonomia é "tipos", seu post-type é portfolios.
Os termos da taxonomia tipos poderiam ser: retangular, quadrado e redondo. Sendo assim vc teria portfolios de 3 tipos diferentes.
Para listar edsses 3 termos, uma das maneiras é criar um template com o seguinte código:

```
$args = array( 'hide_empty=0' );

$terms = get_terms( 'portfolio_tags', $args );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $count = count( $terms );
    $i = 0;
    $term_list = '<p class="my_term-archive">';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $i++;
        $term_list .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain' ), $term->name ) ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        if ( $count != $i ) {
            $term_list .= ' &middot; ';
        }
        else {
            $term_list .= '</p>';
        }
    }
    echo $term_list;
}
```

Veja se serve para você, qualquer coisa só falar.